# How to use get out of jail free card

Tags: monopoly

Scenario, at the start of my turn I roll the dice and land on “Go to jail”.

If I have a “get out of jail free” card, can I play that immediately so my piece does not move, or do I go to jail and must wait for the start of my next turn to play the card.

Comment: Logically, one can't really "get **OUT** of jail" if he's not already **IN** jail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You move your piece to Jail and must wait until the next turn to play the card.**

The [official rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) only talk about using "Get Out of Jail Free" in one place:

> You get out of Jail by... (1) throwing doubles on any of your next
>   three turns; if you succeed in doing this you immediately move
>   forward the number of spaces shown by your doubles throw; even
>   though you had thrown doubles, you do not take another turn;
>   **(2) using the “Get Out of Jail Free” card if you have it**; (3) purchasing
>   the “Get Out of Jail Free” card from another player and playing it;
>   (4) paying a fine of $50 before you roll the dice on either of your next
>   two turns.

There is nothing in the rules that suggests you can use this card to avoid going to Jail.